# Grease quote explanation "Pinkslips ownership papers?"

Tags: slang, meaning-in-context

My son loves Grease and watches it over and over.

So I am starting memorizing it all, but there are some phrases I don't understand.

Please explain exactly what this part means (it is before the car race between Danny and Leo - Scorpion's leader):

Leo: Good, 'cos we're racing for pinks.

Danny: Pinks?

Leo: Pinks, you punk! Pink slips! Ownership papers!

Danny: Oh, ho, ho, ho, ho, ho!

Comment: Not germane to your question, but since you are interested in improving your English: "May you" is almost never idiomatic. "May" is asking for or granting permission, so "May you" doesn't make sense. "Will you", "would you", "can you" or "could you" would all fit here, with very little difference in meaning: "can/could" are a little more tentative than "will/would", and "would/could" are a little more tentative than "will/can", so "Could you" is the most tentative, and so the most polite.

Comment: @Colin: 100% agree that "could you" is politest in British English, but I've heard that "would you" can come across better in the US (at least in some regions/dialects) - but we'd need a US native speaker to confirm :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your punctuation of the last line is wrong. It should be:

> **Leo**: Pinks, you punk. Pink slips. Ownership papers?

In other words, they're racing for pink-colored documents which grant ownership of a car.

(Note that the phrase "pink slip" in English is normally a euphemism for a notice of termination of employment. The usage of "pink slip" in this case is somewhat unusual.)

Comment: so "Pinks" means those documents, "you punk" is somehow "you stupid", "Pink slips" is somehow a way to say "this is a lose or win game" (and as yuo said it is a strange usage of the term), "ownership papers" is an explanation of what "Pinks" mean. Is this correct?

Comment: Not very relevant to the question, but possibly interesting.  Pink slips as a euphemism for notice of termination is not used in British English, and may not work in other dialects.  (Given the prevalence of American media, it's likely most English speakers will know what you mean.  In Britain we would use the term P45, which is the form you are given by your employer to send to the tax man.

Comment: @PimPumPunk "Pink slips" also refer to the documents, as the word "slip" just means a piece of paper.

Comment: Ok so assumin Ben Hocking is right is it correct to say that the following has the same meaning: "Pinks, you stupid. Pinks documents. The cars' owhership papers?"

Comment: @Pim, pretty close. In more idiomatic English I'd paraphrase thusly: *Pinks, you idiot. Pink documents. The cars' ownership papers?*

Comment: At least in my experience, the usage of *pink slip* to mean a car title isn't unusual at all.

Comment: Wow really thanks to all. It is something I wanted to know in the last 4 months. Now I feel i master english some 0.0001% more... Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Dusty: "pink slip" for car title is a very common term in my experience.

Comment: "Racing for slips" or "racing for pinks" is common street racing slang for putting up the loser's car as the prize.

Comment: In California, the title to a car is indeed called a "pink slip." The actual document is (or at least, used to be) pink. I can't recall hearing this terminology on the East coast (the title will look different depending on the state that issues it).

Comment: Since this is slang, I thought this might be germane: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=racin%20for%20pinks&defid=1469066

Comment: @Kit so when Danny hears "we are racing for pinks" he immediately understands what Leo means?

Comment: Just a curiosity: in the italian version the translation is wrong, it says "We are racing for the pink ladies". It really makes no sense. Anyway the italian DVD subtitle is correct, it says "we are racing for the ownership papers".

Comment: Also relevant is the [wikipedia entry for car ownership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_title).  This is US-specific, though; someone in the UK is only likely to know what you mean because they have been watching _Fast and Furious_.

Comment: @PimPumPunk I confess I don't know *Grease* well.  A street racer would know immediately what "slips" meant, but I don't know if Danny was savvy.  "Pink ladies" is actually a kind of apple, so that makes for a pretty funny mis-translation.  Although, isn't "Pink Ladies" one of the groups in *Grease*?

Comment: @Peter Shor That's true, at least in my state the "slips" are actually yellow, hence just "slips." But racers will still know what you mean, I think, if you use "pink slips."

Comment: Also, *punk* is more like "troublemaker."

Comment: @Kit The "Pink ladies" are part of Danny's gang. They are 4 girls. So in italian it seems the race if for the girls, it makes no sense: Danny already "owns" them since they are part of his gang, since California is a free state the "pink ladies" won't like to join Leo's gang. It is clearely an error made by the people who originally dubbed the scene.

Comment: If I recall, the Beach Boys used the term in one of their songs - "Little Deuce Coupe" maybe?

Comment: Leo: Pinks, you punk! Pink slips! Ownership papers! -from the script

Answer (score 0):

*Pinks* is a slang term for ownership documents to a vehicle. The term is still used by most street racers in the US. *Pink slips* are also used for terminating employment, back in the 1950s when this movie was staged, the registration papers were in fact pink.

But he does have a rather sarcastic response in the movie when asked the question "pinks?" He was sarcastic because he thought Danny who was about to race him should have known that reference to the ownership documents to the car considering it is used by most street racers. And they are not racing for the pink ladies they are racing for pink slips— which would mean who wins the race would then own their opponent's vehicle!

And they are not racing for the pink ladies they are racing for pink slips which would mean whomever wins the race with then own their opponents vehicle! More importantly Danny wants to race to prove a point but he ends up getting hurt and isn't able to so his best friend has to race for him. They basically want to show loe that he's not the best at everything.

Comment: Actually, it's Kenickie who was originally supposed to race and got hurt — thus prompting Danny to drive instead.